# Is there a way to prefetch data into the Apollo Server cache?

Tags: apollo-server

I use Apollo Server to turn REST queries into graphql.

One of those REST queries is very slow, so I want to prefetch it regularly (i.e. make the REST call) so that when I make the graphql requests, the data is already in cache.

Comment: Assuming this is a public endpoint can you just run a cron to hit the graphql query on a regular basis?